# I got a connection error in my socket program

Tags: python, sockets

I tried to make a program that connects between a server and client.

Here is the server code:

```
import socket

HOST="127.0.0.1"
PORT=5000

mySocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
mySocket.bind( (HOST, PORT) )

except socket.error:
print ("Call to bind failed")

while 1:
  print("Waiting for connection")
  mySocket.listen(1)

  connection, address=mySocket.accept()
  print("Connection recieved from:", address[0])

  connection.send("SERVER>>> Connection successful")
  clientMessage=connection.recv(1024)

while clientMessage != "Client: end":
    if not clientMessage:
        break

    print (clientMessage)
    serverMessage=input("Server: ")
    connection.send("Server: "+serverMessage)
    clientMessage=connection.recv(1024)

print("Connection ended.")
connection.close()
```

This is the client:

```
import socket
HOST="127.0.0.1"
PORT=5000

print ("Attempting connection")
mySocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
  mySocket.connect( ( HOST, PORT) )
except socket.error:
  print("Call to connect failed")
print ("Connected to server")

serverMessage=mySocket.recv(1024)

while serverMessage!="Server: end":
  if not serverMessage:
      break

  print (serverMessage)
  clientMessage=input("Client: ")
  mySocket.send("Client: "+clientMessage)
  serverMessage=mySocket.recv(1024)

print ("Connection ended.")
mySocket.close()
```

This is the error:

```
 File "C:/Python34/python 3.4/client.py", line 13, in <module>
 serverMessage=mySocket.recv(1024)
 OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed          because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using   a sendto call) no address was supplied
```

The error says I did something wrong with the address(?)

I cant understand what the error wants from me. Can you help me?

Comment: Did the client print "Call to connect failed" or "Connected to server"?

Comment: call to connect failed

Comment: I assume you started the server first. BTW, there are indentation errors in your server code.

Comment: Ok that's why the recv() method failed, your client did not connect to the socket properly. Did you start the server first?

Comment: Which one to start first?

Comment: The server.py program

Comment: I started the server first and i got this error

Comment: You're never going to break out of that `while 1` loop by the way

Comment: Can someone tell me what to fix???

Comment: I just ran your programs they work fine minus fixing some bad indentation (which probably happened when you posted this). Yes the server gets stuck in the `while 1` loop but the client can connect fine.

Comment: Fix your logic. There's no point in the except: statements printing then continuing because the code below is then executed which assumes a connection has been made. Or perhaps that's just the crappy indenting in what you pasted.

Comment: Tried with python 2.7.11 and python 3.5.1. In both environments the client can connect, although in python 3 the server fails shortly after because you are trying to send a str when you should be sending bytes.

Comment: You leave your server running and run the client as a separate process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I made some edits to both of your programs. You need to handle sending and receiving data over the socket as a byte array since you are using python 3. The client and server programs below worked for me using python 3.5.1. Hope this helps.

Also I got rid of your `while 1` infinite loop in the server and removed the try/except statements as I didn't feel they added anything. If you are going to except the socket.error you should at least quit the program at that point since that is a fatal error here.

server.py

```
import socket

HOST="127.0.0.1"
PORT=5000

mySocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mySocket.bind( (HOST, PORT) )
mySocket.listen(1)
print("Waiting for connection")

connection, address=mySocket.accept()
print("Connection recieved from:", address[0])

connection.send(bytearray("SERVER>>> Connection successful", "utf-8"))
clientMessage=connection.recv(1024)

while clientMessage != "Client: end":
    if not clientMessage:
        break

    print (clientMessage)
    serverMessage=input("Server: ")
    connection.send(bytearray("Server: "+serverMessage, "utf-8"))
    clientMessage=connection.recv(1024)

print("Connection ended.")
connection.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket
HOST="127.0.0.1"
PORT=5000

print ("Attempting connection")
mySocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mySocket.connect( ( HOST, PORT) )
print ("Connected to server")

serverMessage=mySocket.recv(1024)

while serverMessage!="Server: end":
  if not serverMessage:
      break

  print (serverMessage)
  clientMessage=input("Client: ")
  mySocket.send(bytearray("Client: "+clientMessage, "utf-8"))
  serverMessage=mySocket.recv(1024)

print ("Connection ended.")
mySocket.close()
```

Comment: It says to me that the target machine actively refused it

Comment: Close the server and the client. Run the command `netstat -a` and see if any connections are using port 5000.

Comment: Can you show me a code of it? I didn't understand clearly

Comment: Run this in Terminal or Powershell: http://serverfault.com/questions/2699/how-do-i-see-if-a-port-is-in-use-on-a-windows-machine/2711

Comment: That's ok, there should be many in use. You are only looking to see if something else is already using 5000. If you want just try changing the port to something else, 5001, 5666, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106721/discussion-between-pholtz-and-daniel-engel).